# Duplicate byte in bytearray

Tags: python

I have a bytearray in which I want to duplicate all occurrences of a given value.

The solution I have currently does work, but I am sure there must be a more elegant way. But how?

```
x = bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xff, 0x04, 0x05])
r = 0xff

skip = False

for i, v in enumerate(x):
    if skip:
        skip = False
        continue
    if v == r:
        x.insert(i, r)
        skip = True

print(x)
```

`bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\xff\xff\x04\x05')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `.replace` method for this task following way:

```
x = bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xff, 0x04, 0x05])
r = b'\xff'
dx = x.replace(r, r*2)
print(dx)
```

output:

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\xff\xff\x04\x05')
```

`.replace` of `bytearray` is similar to `str` method with same name. Note that `r` should be bytes-like, so I used `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator function which emits each item in the input, and emits it again if it is the value to be duplicated:

```
def repeat_value(values, repeating_value):
    for v in values:
        yield v
        if v == repeating_value:
            yield v
```

You need to convert the result back to a `bytearray`:

```
>>> bytearray(repeat_value(x, r))
bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\xff\xff\x04\x05')
```

It also works for any other kind of iterable:

```
>>> ''.join(repeat_value('hello world', 'o'))
'helloo woorld'
>>> list(repeat_value(range(10), 5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value `r` won't change while the function is running, and the order doesn't matter, you can simply count the number of occurrences, and append them all at once.

```
x.extend([r] * x.count(r))
```